# Are there any guarantees for the order of Firebase events

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I may have missed this in the documentation but are there any guarantees that we can rely on in terms of the ordering of events in Firebase (the real-time database)?

For example:

- do events on a ref come before events on any children of that ref?
- do value events come before child_added/removed/etc.?
- if an object is created/destroyed is there any order in which it’s children will receive events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*firebaser here*

A `value` event comes after all `child_` events for the same update to the same ref. This is documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-event-guarantees).

I don't think there was ever a guarantee for the order of events between different levels in the tree. I doubt it ever changed though.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I assume that there’s no ordering within a child as well right? (I.e. when object A that has children B and C is destroyed, there’s no guarantee as to B or C get chil_removed events, etc.)